# how to add touch controls in aframe

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

How to add touch controls for **mobile** and **mouse click** for desktop in aframe.I am getting confusing with this part in aframe is there any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [mouse-component](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component), the raycasts emitted from the mouse clicks seem to work as well with mobile touch events.

---

Note, that You may run into multiple issues when You use the a cursor, and the mouse-cursor-component simultaneously. For example it is possible to make a double click ( one with the component, second with the cursor ).

Comment: **click**  event for mobile is working but the problem is while I take the finger from the mobile the content is still visible there

Comment: @KumareshR I don't quite understand, do You have a problem that the click occurs twice or something ?

Comment: no I want to add touch control for mobile how to do

Comment: @KumareshR You mean You want to rotate the camera with touching Your phone ? disable the gyro rotation ? or you want to emit clicks with touching elements ?

Comment: Yes it emit clicks with touching elements

Comment: @KumareshR when i use the linked component, I am able to click elements by touching them, I didn't quite get what is happening when you take your finger off the screen.

Comment: ensoimmersive.co.in/webvr/1RK/ check this site in mobile u'll get what I am trying there are three info icons interact with touch

Comment: @KumareshR works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/ev4hf4Lg/ Touching the sphere/box triggers the click event. Most of the code is taken from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204267/aframe-cycle-through-colors-using-array. And pls disable those overlays on mobile, I couldn't see much :P

Comment: For desktop I am using mouse enter and mouse leave, what I want to use here for mobile ?

Comment: use 'click'. mouseenter/mouseleave are good for HOVERING events, when you hover the mouse over the object :)

Comment: yeah I am use the click control here the problem is when I touch the icon the text is visible that's cool working great but when I take the finger from that Icon the text is not going means the text is still visible there R u get what I am saying?

Comment: I add this code for disabling gaze in desktop and mobile while adding these code click control is not working

Comment: var cursorEl = document.querySelector('a-cursor');

if (!AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile() ) 



{
  cursorEl.parentEl.removeChild(cursorEl);
}

Comment: @KumareshR I'm afraid mouseleave won't work in any form, I tried using other events, like touchstart, touchend, but I would suggest making these markers toggle'able on click, not on hover. Click -> visible, Click ->invisible. I wanted to make it visible while the finger is down, but it would require creating a new component utilizing the touch events, as i cant find any existing ones.

Comment: Have you tried using Ray Input? It standardizes everything with touch, mouse, 0DOF, 3DOF and even 6DOF.

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski how to add compass in aframe scene based on mouse click and drag rotation the compass should rotate like in facebook 360 videos they are using the same thing